# Convert 64 character hex String to BINARY(32)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an input in the form of "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"(64 hexadecimal characters obtained from SHA-256) which I want to store in a database with MySqli. The column the value should be inserted to is of type BINARY(32). 
I think that the value is interpreted as a string, rather than a hex number, so MySQL returns "Data too long for column x at row y".
How can I convert this string to 32 bytes in PHP?
I already tried adding "0x" as a prefix, MySql's CONVERT function and I read about hex2bin and bin2hex, which don't seem to do what I want, and i tried both string and int types in bind_params (int results in 0x3000... regardless of the input)

Thanks in advance

Comment: hex2bin should do what you want. Why do you say it doesn't?

Comment: I just realized that I set the type to be String inside bind_param, however if i change it to int, the resulting entry in the database is not my input, but 0x300....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Joni's comment is the answer, i thought about hex2bin just as a way to make hex-encoded string readable, and i didn't realize it compresses the hex value to a string which is short enough to be stored as binary. Thanks to joni and tkausl for enduring my incompetence in php and in managing stackoverflow questions :)

EDIT: i can't close the question since the answer was posted as a comment, sorry for that.